# Grouping the list by a field and add items to a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class.

```
public class Compaints
{
    public string CustomerNumber{get; set;},

    public string Complaint{get; set} 
}
```

I have a list of complaints. I need to group by customerNumber and add it to dictionary say of type
`Dictionary<string, int>` - string will be customer number and int will be count.

How to do this in linq?

Thanks.

Comment: LINQ's no silver bullet. You could have done it with a simple FOR-loop in the same time you spent for asking…

Comment: Yeah, but using LINQ will make the code bit cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var countByCustomer = complaints.GroupBy(row => row.CustomerNumber)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
```